# What are security risks when running an Erlang cluster?

Tags: security, erlang

It's more a general question in terms of what one has to look out for when running an Erlang system. For example, I know of atom exhaustion attacks. What are other possible attacks and how to make your system more secure?

Answer (score 5):

Running a cluster means they are sharing a cookie, and if one knows the cookie than they can attach to any of your nodes (assuming they are attached to your network) and execute any arbitrary Erlang command or program.

So my thought is that clustered means that there are at least two files (and some number of people) who know what the cookie is (or where to find it).

Comment: I think that erlang host must not be available to public access

Comment: I meant epmd, and high ports of net_kernel

Comment: As [reference](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id87338) says, two nodes are able to connect with different cookies. But one must know each other's cookie anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would be afraid of bugs in applications deployed in your system. Good example from otp is SSL app, which was completely re-written 3 years ago. The next would be http client - memory leaks. Xmerl was never a strong part of the system.

Also, be careful with 3rd party Erlang apps: new web servers (probably better than inets, but if you do not need all the performance consider stable Yaws), ejabberd - number of techniques hitting directly OS, Riak - interaction with filesystem, ulimit, iostats etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to have your Cluster in a closed VPN (if they are far apart and parhaps communicate over a WAN). Then, you want to run them atop hardened `UNIX` or `LINUX`. Another strong idea is to close all epmd connections to your cluster even if one has got the cookie by using `net_kernel:allow(Nodes).` 
One of the main Weaknesses of Erlang Vms (i have come to realise) is memory consumption. I think that if an Erlang Platform providing service to many users and its NOT protected against DOS attacks, its left really vulnerable. You need to limit number of allowed concurrent connections for the Web Servers so that you can easilly block out some *`script boys in the neighbourhood`*. Another situation is having distributed/replicated `Mnesia` database across your cluster. Mnesia replicates data but i ain't sure if that data is encrypted. Lastly, ensure that you are the sole administrator of all the machines in your cluster.